# How to use pyleargist in python 3?

Tags: python, pip

Whenever i try to pip install pyleargist, it gives me this issue.

[image]

Is there a version compatible with python 3 ?
Can someone help on this ?

Comment: Please always post errors *as code* not as pictures.

Answer (score 2):

The library was last updated in 2012, see the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pyleargist/2.0.5/#history) and as you already noticed, the issue you are seeing is based on the fact that it was written for python 2. In this case, `file` seems to be used in the `setup.py`, which was removed in python3. For this exact library, it seems to be stale, so no other versions.

You have two options:

1. It does not look to be a large library, you could [download the source code](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/4a/2eef58a73c48aec6aca09254ef0f39148fd39b8dc7ec96d6b39d513b03eb/pyleargist-2.0.5.tar.gz) from pypi and try to fix the python 2/3 issues.
2. Search for another library. A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=GIST+global+image+descriptors+python) shows several options for python libraries that can compute the GIST descriptor. Just look for another one that fits your requirements